# A SharePoint Demo

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there some demo available somewhere, to use to present SharePoint for a company? With some fictive departments (Economy, HR...and so on), and with fictive employees with their access rights? So I could for example "log in" as an economy department member, and I see only economy related stuff?

For example, some collection of Excel files easy to import to SharePoint.

Comment: Are you a Microsoft partner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a Microsoft partner they have 90 days demo tenants that you can order and be up and running in a few minutes with demo data and everything. You can find it here: [https://demos.microsoft.com](https://demos.microsoft.com/environments/create-tenant)

[image]

Comment: @brennmar, O thank you for looking at this as well! That certainly looks great. I'll just have to resolve some permissions to get going!

Answer (score 1):

there are some companies working in sharePoint implementation projects , you may contact any of them and they may provide you with this demo.

also you can subscribe in **[Office 365 Enterprise E3](https://signup.microsoft.com/Signup?OfferId=B07A1127-DE83-4a6d-9F85-2C104BDAE8B4&dl=ENTERPRISEPACK&Country=US&culture=en-us&ali=1#0)** trail (30 days) SharePoint online included.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean something like this: http://www.buchanan.com/sharepoint/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try pnp starter kit for getting some sites up and running with nice WebParts and some fictional sites.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit

In this moment i think your tenant has to be in Targeted release since atleast 1 WebPart is using the beta calls on MSGraphClient.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Microsoft Labs available: 
https://www.microsoft.com/handsonlabs/SelfPacedLabs#keywords=sharepoint&page=1&sort=Newest

Hope this helps!
Ova